# MySql SELECT WHERE Date is greater than past 10 weeks (starting at prev Sunday)

Tags: mysql, date, dayofweek, weekday

The problem I'm running into is when running this query it starts the week interval from the current date (minus 7 days from current date).  I want to do all previous 10 weeks (Sun-Mon).  So if my current date is on a Monday, Tuesday, or Wednesday, I want it to start on the most recent Sunday then look back at the previous 10 weeks.  I believe I have to use `WEEKDAY` or `DAYOFWEEK` in the `DATE_SUB` but have tried with no avail:

```
SELECT
    SUM(MT.QUANTITY) as qty,
    WEEKDAY(MT.TRANS_DATE) AS WEEKDAY,
    WEEK(MT.TRANS_DATE) AS WEEK,
    YEAR(MT.TRANS_DATE) AS YEAR
FROM
    mytable MT
WHERE
        MT.TRANS_DATE > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 WEEK)
GROUP BY WEEK
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),WEEK(CURDATE()),' Sunday'), '%X%V %W'),INTERVAL 10 WEEK)`, like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(MT.QUANTITY) as qty,
    WEEKDAY(MT.TRANS_DATE) AS WEEKDAY,
    WEEK(MT.TRANS_DATE) AS WEEK,
    YEAR(MT.TRANS_DATE) AS YEAR
FROM
    mytable MT
WHERE
        MT.TRANS_DATE > DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),WEEK(CURDATE()),' Sunday'), '%X%V %W'),INTERVAL 10 WEEK)
GROUP BY WEEK
```

Also you can use the other way pilcrow suggested:

```
SUBDATE(CURDATE(), DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) - 1)
```

Which is a little more readable...

Comment: +1  I find computing "this week's Sunday" as `SUBDATE(CURDATE(), DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) - 1)` a little easier to read than string manipulation, FWIW.  Shouldn't make any difference in execution, however, since both are constant.